# Получить комментарии к ячейке Google Spreadsheets PHP

Tags: php, google-spreadsheet

Данные в ячейке получаю так

```
$rangeD4 = 'Лист1!D4';
$responseC4 = $service->spreadsheets_values->get($spreadsheetId, $rangeD4, ['valueRenderOption' => 'FORMATTED_VALUE']);
var_dump($responseC4->values);
```

Я как получить комментарий к данной ячейке?

Answer (score 0):

Нашел, данные можно получить так

Долго гуглил и в принципе данные получаются так

```
$spreadsheet = $service->spreadsheets->get($spreadsheetId, ['includeGridData' => true]);
    $sheet = $spreadsheet->getSheets();
    //$formats = $sheet[0]['data'][0]['rowData'][0]['values'];
  var_dump($sheet[0]['data'][0]['rowData'][17]['values'][5]['note']);
```

где 17 это строка минус 1
5 - столбец минус 1